# Linking two circles in three dimensions

Tags: general-topology

Following [this link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LKkXXx0VYPMC&pg=PT22&dq=linking%20two%20circles%20in%20three%20dimension&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs0Z7L5o3MAhWKoZQKHV-KBl0Q6wEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=linking%20two%20circles%20in%20three%20dimension&f=false), consider the following statement,

> 9. You can link two circles in three dimensions....

I didn't find any intuition for proof or any proof of it. How can we prove this?

Comment: Google Hopf link.

Comment: Please just write out the question rather than linking to it, you can have the link too but it's good to have the full question.